# How to solve $0=\dot{y}-\dot{y}^2-y-t^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was messing around with some differential equations(long story involving a game of snake, a game of minesweeper, chemical bonds, a basketball, and a friend) when I made a mistake and got the equation $0=\dot{y}-\dot{y}^2-y-t^2$. However, this seemed like a much more interesting equation than what I should've got but I couldn't figure out how to solve this which brought me here. Could someone give me a hint or point me towards some reading or techniques that could help me solve it?  Thanks.

I apologize if I violated any customs of MSE or rules, I'm not familiar.

Comment: Have you managed to guess a solution?

Comment: No, not yet. I keep on running into either $\dot{y}^2$ or $y$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha does come up with solutions to this nonlinear ODE, but they’re quite lengthy ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y’%28t%29-y’%28t%29%5E2%3Dy%28t%29%2Bt%5E2)).

Comment: "Quite lengthy" indeed

Comment: Oh yeah. There is no way I would've gotten that. What's $\xi$ supposed to represent here?

Comment: @4a24192a All the greek letters are integration variables. But looking closer, I don't even think those solutions are done, because they use $y(t)$ as a variable all over they the place, and then equates to $c_1$ in the end. I think wolfram alpha just "reduced" the problem to these other equations... Thanks, Wolfram, very helpful

Comment: It looks like $y(t)$ is the inverse function of an integral which cannot be done in closed form.

Comment: So no elementary solution exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a general solution (and the wolframalpha link suggests that the general solution is horrible...).

But an Ansatz of $y = at^2 + bt + c$ actually gives two complex valued particular solutions straightforwardly. Let $r$ be a root of $4z^2+z+1$, i.e.
$$
r=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{15}}{8}.
$$
Then
$$
y(t) = r\cdot t^2 + \frac{r+1}{2}\cdot t + \frac{r+5}{16}
$$
is a solution for either choice of $r$.

---

You could also go for power series. If $y=\sum_n a_n t^n$, then $\dot y=\sum_n (n+1)a_{n+1} t^n$. Using this, we have
$$
t^2 
= - y + y' - (y')^2 
= \sum_n  \left( - a_n + (n+1)a_{n+1} - \sum_{j+k=n}(j+1)(k+1)a_{j+1}a_{k+1}\right)t^n 
= : \sum_n b_n t^n.
$$
So
$$
b_n = \begin{cases}0 & n\ne 2 \\ 1 & n=2\end{cases}
$$
lets you solve recursively for $a_n$. In fact, $a_0 = a_1(1-a_1)$ and
$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{\delta_{n,2} + a_n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k+1)(n-k+1)a_{k+1}a_{n-k+1}}{(n+1)(1-2a_1)}
, \quad n\ge1.
$$
**In particular, there should be exactly two solutions for each initial condition $y(0) \ne \frac14$.**

Here are some numeric real solutions from maple. Note the parabola $y=t^2+\frac14$. Beyond that, $y'$ would have to be complex.

[image]

Comment: Alright, thanks

Comment: By the way, on the "critical parabola", $y'=\frac12$ for both solutions meeting at that point (using a one-sided derivative). I think there is also a pair of solutions meeting from the left at $(0,\frac 14)$. We couldn't make a power series for those because they only exist for $t\le0$. I think.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks